# MacBook Boots into GNU Grub after installing ElementaryOS on external Hard drive

Tags: catalina, startup, grub

I have an external SSD (240GB) which I wanted to partition in order to install a portable version of Linux on it and have the option of running it from any Computer.
When I plug the SSD in and start the MacBook, it boots directly into the Linux - Elementary OS. **so far so good**.

My problem now is, that when I have nothing plugged in, the Mac automatically boots into the GNU Grub and then says something like "no hard drive". I have to **hold the `option-key`** to select the Startup Disk and the click on MacOs HDD.

In the System Settings there is not option to change the Boot settings, because there is only my MacOs HDD.

Im using MacOs Catalina 10.15.5

MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports)

Does anyone know why this happens? I wasn't able to find any useful help online...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you hold down the option key, you will get the Mac Startup Manager. Hold down the control key and select to boot to macOS.

Comment: @DavidAnderson That was not really my issue -- i know how to get it to boot into mac. the problem is that if i dont press the option key while booting it will always go into the GNU grub and expect the external hard drive with Linux on it. i then have to reboot and always hold the option key for MacOS

Comment: Holding down the control key when selecting a label from the Mac Startup Manager will make the selection the default.

Comment: So i hold down the option key while booting the Laptop in order to see the startup manager. Once i have the choice, i select the MacOs HDD while holding the option key and press enter. It didnt change it though -- by default it remains booting into the GNU Grub 2.0

Comment: For a third time, I will write it. You press and hold down the **CONTROL** key while making your selection. You will see the straight arrow change to a circular arrow.

Comment: Additionally, you state in your question that macOS appears in the Startup Disk pane of System Preferences. All you have to do is highlight icon above the macOS label and macOS will become the default. I suggest you try this.